# How to deduce operator precedence from a string input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, operator-precedence

I am a beginner to Python. I have tried learning python and C++ in the past had learnt about like classes and stuff but then had to abandon it for reasons, now I am learning python from the beginning as I have forgotten it all.

So I was trying to make a calculator like the ones you have in mobile using python but without any GUI. Now, the problem I am having right now is, see in your mobile calculator you can do one operation after the other i.e. say you typed 95+8x2, that mobile calculator will have no problem in deducing operator precedence from your input and give result as 111 and I am trying to do something similar.

But the problem is, the way I know how to do it as a beginner would require a lot of code, it would not be complex but get too long and hence a lot of time wasted. Here is how I have thought of doing it right now :

Find the location of each of the operators in the input for that I am using their indexes i.e. I have named the input as '`alg_operation`' and for example, I am using `alg_operation.find('*')` to where the multiplaction operator is, I am calling this index as `location_prod` using this I am able to calculate the product simply via converting the part of the string that comes before the operator into float then multiply it with the other part that comes just after (obviously converting it into float as well).

After finding the location of each of the 5 operators that I have decided to include i.e. exponentiation, multiplication, division (// not /), addition and subtraction, I would have to write code for 120 different cases of the arrangement of these operators, which may not be complex but definitely will take a lot of time.

**How can I quickly deduce operator precedence from the string input ?**

I will update this post if I learn anything new, since I am a beginner to programming.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: Incidentally, I realise your just trying to be clear, but I really hate questions in **bold**.  with SO in dark mode they are almost unreadable

Comment: btw, if you just want to write a python calculator and are content with python's order of precedence, the simplest answer would be 'don't': just wait for the whole input and then evaluate it, and let python handle precendence for you.  If you're interested in writing a parser, though, see @chepner's link above.

Comment: @2e0byo, I am interested in writing my own parser but your solution also piques my interest, how would one do what you have suggested ? say If the input 4+5-2*2**3, how would that be converted to telling python that its not a string but instead do the mathematical operations like the interpreter normally does

Comment: You would have to use `eval`, which evaluates *any* Python expression, not just arithmetic expressions. I strongly recommend against doing that, especially on untrusted user input.

Comment: do you recommend against using eval or against using my own parser ?

Comment: I recommend against using `eval`. Writing your own parser is the right way to go, because then you are in complete control over how the parsed result gets used.

Comment: @chepner I had a few questions after reading that wikipedia article, if you could please answer those, as per my understanding I would have to still find the indexes of the various operators then compare them as to which one is the smallest, then it would be the first one in the operator stack. using that information, I can do the rest, right ? But how do I sort those various indices in an ascending order ? I don't know much python yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed evaluate an arbitrary python expression with `eval`.  Use of `eval` is a pretty big code smell, because it lets you execute *anything*, but for completeness it would be done like this:

```py
expr = input("Please, please, please only write maths: ")
print(eval(exp))
```

note that you could type `import shutil; shutil.rmtree("/home")` and python would cheerfully run it.  So obviously we don't want to do this.

We could try to protect ourselves by sanitising the input.  In this case this might actually work, with something like:

```py
safe_chars = (".", "*", "+", "/", "-"," ", *range(10))
if not all(x in safe_chars for x in expr):
    raise ValueError("You tried to enter dangerous data!")
```

I can't immediately think of any way to do anything dangerous with input consisting only of those chars, but doubtless someone will point it out immediately in the comments [in which case I'll add it here].  More generally, sanitising data like this is hard, because in order to know what's safe you really need to *understand* the input, by which point you've just written a parser.

Please do note that `eval` is inherently dangerous.  It can be a useful hack for once-off code, although even then... and it is of course useful when you actually want to evaluate python code.

Answer (score 0):

Converting it to [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) will solve your problem

```
def readNumber(string: str,index: int):
    number = ""
    while index < len(string) and isNumber(string[index]):
        number += string[index]
        index += 1
    return float(number), index


def isOperator(token):
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%']
    return token in operators

def isNumber(token):
    return (token >= '0' and token <= '9') or token == "."



def toRpn(string: str):
    """
    Converts infix notation to reverse polish notation
    """
    precedence = {
        '(': 0,
        '-': 1,
        '+': 1,
        '*': 2,
        '/': 2,
        '%': 2,
    }

    i = 0
    fin = []
    ops = []

    while i < len(string):
        token = string[i]
        if isNumber(token):
            number, i = readNumber(string,i)
            fin.append(number)
            continue
        if isOperator(token):
            top = ops[-1] if ops else None
            if top is not None and precedence[top] >= precedence[token]:
                fin.append(ops.pop())
            ops.append(token)
            i += 1
            continue
        if token == '(':
            ops.append(token)
            i += 1
            continue
        if token == ')':
            while True:
                operator = ops.pop()
                if operator == '(':
                    break
                fin.append(operator)
                if not ops:
                    break
            i += 1
            continue
        i += 1
    while ops:
        fin.append(ops.pop())
    return fin

def calculate_rpn(rpn: list):
    """
    Calculates the result of an expression in reverse polish notation
    """
    stack = []
    for token in rpn:
        if isOperator(token):
            a = stack.pop()
            b = stack.pop()
            if token == '+':
                stack.append(b + a)
            elif token == '-':
                stack.append(b - a)
            elif token == '*':
                stack.append(b * a)
            elif token == '/':
                stack.append(b / a)
            elif token == '%':
                stack.append(b % a)
        else:
            stack.append(token)
    return stack[0]
        

print ("90165: ", calculate_rpn(toRpn("27+38+81+48*33*53+91*53+82*14+96")))
print ("616222: ", calculate_rpn(toRpn("22*26*53+66*8+7*76*25*44+78+100")))
print (calculate_rpn(toRpn("(22+4)*4")))
```

[My Github](https://github.com/noah1400/rpn-calculator/blob/main/python/rpn-calculator.py)

You can easily add more operators and their precedence if you want.
You have to modify the `precedence` array and the `isOperator` function. Also you should modify the function of the respective operator in the `calculate_rpn` function.